# Import excel spreadsheet into Oracle using sdcli command line tool

Tags: import, excel-2010, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I'm attempting to into import oracle 11gR2 using the command line tool for SqlDeveloper 4.0. The ultimate reason is we are attempting to import a lot of freetext fields that need to preserve the exact formatting. CR LF, etc for legal reasons. End users need to edit these in Excel.

SQLLoader baulks at the CR LF's, You can achieve this in SqlDeveloper by switching the formatting to UTF-8 for import / export. We are now trying to build up some scripts after discovering how to do this in the command line runtime sdcli64... BUT there doesn't appear to be an option to import from a flat file or .xlsx in that utility??

Any pointers or are we missing an obvious parameter?

(we are using the latest version of SqlDeveloper we can find, 4.03)

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

New version of Oracle developer 4.1 was released as an Early adopter today. You can run the sdcli or sdcli64 command line version with the new parameters. This will import excel files as possible in the sqlDeveloper GUI and it will preserve the formatting using the new [-utility] switch.

You can then use the scripting tool/method of choice to build scripts to do all files in a directory, etc.

Comment: the question is, what does the contents of the importconfig.xml required look like. I cant find a resource anywhere or any documentation.

Comment: asking yourself questions on Oracle early adopter features is like screaming in space. Im not going to accept my answer until I finish it :)

Answer (score 0):

With new SQL Developer 4.1 you may import XLSX file (and other formats too) via command line:
Use sdcli utility import.

You will need a config XML file. To create one, start the import in the UI, configure the columns, etc, and at the last step click the button 'Save State'. It will create an XML file you may re-use in command line.